# Tensorflow - How to use GPU for input_fn with Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I am currently using the [resnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/22a00338e8b51a714955ea6ba4a03c6d3cf86b66/official/resnet) training code from the official models branch of tensorflow and I am facing an issue with respect to the device placement of input_fn when invoked from the Estimator.

The default device placement is always CPU when input_fn is invoked from _call_input_fn inside the Estimator class - [[r1.8 source]](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L797).

```
with ops.device('/cpu:0'):
  return input_fn(**kwargs)
```

Although the official documentation recommends the input data pipeline to be placed on the CPU so that the GPU is used only for training, there can be scenarios where one needs to perform a forward inference during the data loading phase. For example, during adversarial attacks to perturb the input image by computing the gradients with respect to the input.

Is there a way to override the explicit CPU device placement for input data loading when using Estimators?

Comment: Also having a similar request